# css ignored when element is inserted by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written this code, which inserts icons in my div with id="editor". When I add `<select>`
to the div with `id="drug_tool"`, css rules for styling it are ignored. How can I get rid of this problem?

Here is my code

```
<div id="editor"></div>

<script>
    var ni = document.getElementById('editor');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'glavni';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);

    var ni = document.getElementById('glavni');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'toolbar';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);

    var ni = document.getElementById('toolbar');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'prvi_tool';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = 
            '<img src="images_zadaca/cut.png" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;">   \
            <img src="images_zadaca/copy.png" onclick="removeElement(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/paste.png" onclick="removeElement(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/redo.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'redo\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/undo.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'undo\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/bold.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/italic.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'italic\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/underline.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'underline\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_center.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyCenter\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_justify.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyFull\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_left.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyLeft\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_right.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyRight\')" style="cursor:pointer;">';
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);

    var ni = document.getElementById('toolbar');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'drugi_tool';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = 
            '  \
        <select id="select2" onchange="bojaFonta()"> \
            <option value="red">Red</option> \
            <option value="blue">Blue</option> \
            <option value="green">Green</option> \
            <option value="black">Black</option> \
            <option value="white">White</option> \
        </select>  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/copy.png" onclick="removeElement(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/paste.png" onclick="removeElement(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/redo.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'redo\')" style="cursor:pointer;">  \
            <img src="images_zadaca/undo.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'undo\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/bold.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'bold\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/italic.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'italic\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/underline.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'underline\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_center.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyCenter\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_justify.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyFull\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_left.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyLeft\')" style="cursor:pointer;"> \
            <img src="images_zadaca/align_right.png" onclick="izmijeni(\'justifyRight\')" style="cursor:pointer;">';
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);


</script>
```

Comment: the id is drugi_tool with an i isn't it?

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two styles you can apply to `select` are `color` and `background-color`.

[MSDN has the details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored. In addition, style settings applied directly to individual options override those applied to the containing select element as a whole.

Comment: Really, I didn't know that. It's no matter if I have defined css rules for <select> which is inserted with javascript? Does this happen to some other elements?

Comment: Yeah:

<form>
<fieldset>
<label>
<output>